# How to Mock Imported Functions

Tags: javascript, function, import, es6-modules, spy

I have a Typescript library that is exporting individual functions that are not bound together in a class, allowing them to be tree shaken by any consuming application via webpack.

I am looking to write clean unit tests, which is easy to do for most functions. However, there are some composite functions whose behavior is wholly delegated to one or more functions.

### Example

In this example, the implementation of `getType` is wholly based on the behavior of two other functions. It therefore makes sense to test it based solely on the behavior of those called functions. This is exactly why testing libraries support spying.

Library Code

```js
export function getType(value: string): 'FOO' | 'BAR' | 'OTHER' {
  return isFoo(value) ? 'FOO' : isBar(value) ? 'BAR' : 'OTHER';
}
export function isFoo(value: string): boolean {
  const regex = /crazyComplexFooRegex/;
  return regex.test(value);
}
export function isBar(value: string): boolean {
  const regex = /crazyComplexBarRegex/;
  return regex.test(value);
}
```

Test Code:

```js
import * as FooBarUtils from './foobar-utils';
import createSpy = jasmine.createSpy;
fdescribe('FooBar Utils', () => {
  it('getType should return FOO type if isFoo', () => {
    (FooBarUtils as any).isFoo = createSpy("isFoo").and.returnValue(true); // ERROR
    (FooBarUtils as any).isBar = createSpy("isBar").and.returnValue(false);
    expect(FooBarUtils.getType("value doesn't matter")).toBe('FOO');
  });
});
```

This results in `TypeError: Cannot set property isFoo of [object Module] which has only a getter`.

NOTE: This is actually part of a larger Angular CLI project that includes Webpack bundling.

### Thoughts

- I tried an older library that purported to solve this problem, but failed with the same error message. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports but got the same results.
- I followed a suggestion that worked but required creating test-related code INSIDE my library source code. I didn't like it because it violated the general rule of thumb that code shouldn't do special things just for testing purposes. See https://railsware.com/blog/mocking-es6-module-import-without-dependency-injection/
- Many suggestions recommend using Dependency Injection (DI) to solve the problem, but that requires the library to restructure itself just so it can be tested.

### Final Thoughts

<s>I feel like the solution-space for this might be to utilize a tsconfig.spec.json that is configured so that TypeScript generates less encapsulated Javascript output? Does Typescript even have configuration options to support this?</s>

EDIT: This may be more related to Javascript module encapsulation than Typescript. Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a TypeScript thing, it's a JavaScript thing. Modules records are not mutable. That's how they are specified. If you ask me, I think you are over complicating things. Test the public api, the function's interface.

Comment: This is probably a Javascript module thing-- I have updated the post. I both agree and disagree with you over "over complicating things". Functions should be tested based on their inputs and expected outputs. But sometimes, the business logic being tested is related to the behavior of other functions-- so you shouldn't need to test all the combinations of all behaviors of all the used functions.